# HTTP 200 (OK) returned instead of 301 (Moved Permanently)

Tags: node.js, http-error, node-fetch

This URL returns a code 301 to `wget` and `curl`, but `node-fetch` is reporting 200:

```sh
# wget https://www.h24info.ma/feed
--2021-03-19 11:30:23--  https://www.h24info.ma/feed
Resolving www.h24info.ma (www.h24info.ma)... 104.21.39.120, 172.67.145.67, 2606:4700:3030::6815:2778, ...
Connecting to www.h24info.ma (www.h24info.ma)|104.21.39.120|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
```

```sh
# curl -I https://www.h24info.ma/feed
HTTP/2 301
```

But fetch returns 200 (and hangs forever) :

```js
fetch('https://www.h24info.ma/feed', {
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36',
  'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml'
}).then(function (res) {

  console.error('node-fetch status: %s', res.status);
});

node-fetch status: 200
```

Am I missing something? Fetch should return 301 so the request can be aborted and the error dealt with.

| software | version |
| --- | --- |
| node-fetch | 2.6.1 |
| node | v14.15.3 |
| npm | 7.6.0 |
| Operating System | Linux 4.9.0-15-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.258-1 (2021-03-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `fetch` follows redirects transparently. That is, if the URL requested returns a 301/302 redirect response code, `fetch` will automatically make another request to the redirect URL, and the response you get will be the one from that second request.

You can configure this behaviour via the `redirect` field in the fetch options object:

```
fetch(URL, {
  redirect: 'manual' // do not follow redirects automatically
})
```

[Check out the MDN docs for `fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) for more information.

> Fetch should return 301 so the request can be aborted and the error dealt with.

A 301 status is not really an error, so in my opinion the default behaviour of `fetch` is correct. In most cases, what you want is `fetch` to request the resource specified, regardless of where it actually is. To that end, if a server tells `fetch` to look elsewhere for a resource, it will.